# Select percentage of rows from SQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, limit

I've got a site with a PHP script, this script has an SQL query inside returning data that is accessed by a JavaScript file. The data is a huge list of flight data, and I need to be able to select (let's say) a random 40% of the total flights for any given day specified. For arguments sake lets put it like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Flight_Data` WHERE DepDateTimeUTC LIKE '%1/1/14%' ";
```

I understand that to get a random number of rows you simply use `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 40'` and ideally I want to say `LIMIT 40%` but that doesn't work.

EDIT:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Flight_Data` WHERE DepDateTimeUTC LIKE '%1/1/14%' ";
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$total = $row[0];
$percent = $total * 0.40;
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Flight_Data` WHERE DepDateTimeUTC LIKE '%1/1/14%' LIMIT . $percent ";
```

Comment: You can use a workaround, select count all the records, with php calculate the 40% and use that as limit in another query

Comment: @MarcoMura's got it.  Which is pretty much what it says [here](http://flylib.com/books/en/2.305.1.82/1/) (third [google search item](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=math%20expression%20in%20limit%20mysql))

Comment: Depends on implementation.   Some SQL99 implementations (PostgreSQL for example) support expressions in the argument to LIMIT.   Alternatively, SQL2008 FETCH ONLY syntax, if supported, definitely allows expressions.

Comment: @BadZen on mysql (official site) you can do a LIMIT only with integer direct, no calculation (Even 1+1 won't work)

Comment: The only idea I have in mind right now is to get the count and do the calculation before you pass it to LIMIT.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you storing DepDateTimeUTC as a string?  If so, why not as a timestamp/datetime?  You'd be able to use temporal functions such as BETWEEN on the latter.

Comment: If you had a timestamp you could take seconds less than 24 to get 40% (or other tricks with the number of seconds if you think the first half of a minute might introduce a bias)

Comment: you could use row count mod 10 <= 4

Comment: @GordonM the DepDateTimeUTC is a string with the date followed by the time, I'm using between on the latter for another function :)

Comment: @MarcoMura you are a gift my friend I'm trying this now

Comment: @mekk33 if you want the address to give me a gift we can talk :P

Comment: Pur the .$percent after " and before the semicolumn

Comment: And noto select * in the first query but select count(*)

Comment: *"ideally I want to say `LIMIT 40%` but that doesn't work."*. I'm afraid you can't. MySQL only deals with fixed integers with no decimals, therefore you are limited to 1,2,3....40 etc. unless you round off the decimal. Or as [**the manual**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) states `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;` so you'll need a comma in there somehow.

Comment: You can try rounding it off by adding `$rounded = round($percent);` under `$percent = $total * 0.40;`

Comment: Or `$new = number_format($percent, 2, ',', ' ');` which will give you something like `20,20` when using `$total = 50.5;

$percent = $total * 0.40;` as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `COUNT` all records and then calculate the `%` you need like this:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Flight_Data` WHERE DepDateTimeUTC LIKE '%1/1/14%' ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result));

$total = $row[0];
$percent = intval($total * 0.40);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `Flight_Data` WHERE DepDateTimeUTC LIKE '%1/1/14%' LIMIT ". $percent;
//execute your query....
```

Comment: Thanks I'm trying it now! to store the total I'm using this: $total = mysql_fetch_row($query);    is this correct?

Comment: Try this: `$row = mysql_fetch_row($resource); $total = $row[0];`

Comment: Use mysqli_ functions, because all with prefix mysql_ are deprecated.

Comment: You can also remove the empty space on the first query between ' and " at the end of the query

Comment: Execute the query before mysqli_fetch_row `$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);`

Comment: `$percent` will likely contain a decimal so you should cast it to an integer

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using a php script you should be able to achieve what you want. What you can do is, get the total no of rows in the table, which goes like:

`SELECT count(*) AS Total FROM Flight_Data`

With php you can calculate the 40% of that total.

Lets say $myPercent contains the calculated 40% of total. You can use the value of $myPercent in the limit as

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Flight_Data`  
WHERE DepDateTimeUTC LIKE '%1/1/14%'  
LIMIT ".$myPercent;
```

Here, we escape the php variable from the mysql query string which is a good practice.

In mysql, `%` is used as wildcard, so it cannot be used like you thought you could in limit.

Hope this has helped you.

Comment: You forgot the rand function