# Search limited by percentage and by user type

Tags: php, mysql, search, project, search-engine

I am starting a project where I need to do a search based on user type and ranking. If the user have the free plan it only appears in 40% of searches and as the best ranking. To search by ranking I think it's not tricky! But what to do to the search show the free users only 40% of searches?I looked at Oracle and here too, out 43 other websites and found nothing about it. Anyone know of any link or have any idea how to do? Thank you and taking advantage, congratulations to us by 10 million questions! :)

EDIT: (guess this is the way)

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user_type = 'silver'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result));

$total = $row[0];

$percent = intval($total * 0.40);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_type = 'silver' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ". $percent;
```

Okay. Theoretically this will give me 40% of silver users every search. But then I ask: is that correct? The proposal is that the silver users appear in 40% OF TOTAL SEARCHES and not 40% of the total silver entries.

Comment: is this just a math question of how to calculate percentages?

Comment: Hello, @developerwjk !
I guess not. The question is - assuming we have a query like "select * from users order by user_type, ranking" where users free appears only 40% times in this query!

Comment: So you want to only show a partial result of free users? 40%?

Comment: one way is run the query with `count(*)` then based on the total records that would appear, calculate the number of records that would make 40% (lets call it X), and then run the query for real this time with `limit X`

Comment: i.e. like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569929/select-percentage-of-rows-from-sql-table

Comment: @HatemJaber Ideally it is to show the free users only in 40% of search results. But if anyone here not show up with some idea or suggestion about how to do maybe I'll be forced to do based on 40% of free users, alternatively

Comment: @developerwjk Yes my friend! Thank you by pointing this link. This give me the initial idea on how to start. Guess the way is therein. When I write the code, I post here to help anyone with same problem / doubt in future. Between today and tomorrow I'll paste the result here